# Why do i get this exception when starting Tomcat 7 with Activiti BPM

Tags: tomcat7, activiti

I copy Activiti war file to Tomcat webapps and it starts fine and i am able to open Activiti Explorer.

When i reopen Tomcat 7 after Eclipse configured for Activiti (Help->Install new software->http://activiti.org/designer/update/), and restart Tomcat  i get an exception :-

Caused by: java.io.NotSerializableException: org.activiti.workflow.simple.converter.json.SimpleWorkflowJsonConverter at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1183) at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1547) at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:15 08) at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1431) at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1177) at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1547)

Any ideas ?

Thanks.

PS:-I read this comment to a similar error in another thread :-

"The exception you included is just a session serialisation issue, so nothing serious.
But are you experiencing real issues?".

Answer (score 2):

When Tomcat shut down it tries to persist the objects in the user sessions on the disk.
Similarly, when it restart, it tries to load these persisted objects from disk into memory.

This is called [de-]serialization (or [un-]marshalling).

To achieve these operations, the objects to [de-]serialize have to implement the `java.io.Serializable` interface.

In this particular case, it appears that the class `org.activiti.workflow.simple.converter.json.SimpleWorkflowJsonConverter`does not implement this interface.

To prevent disk [de-]serialization, simply uncomment the "Manager" XML element in *${tomcat-dir]/conf/context.xml* file.

(source: http://mihail.stoynov.com/2011/04/11/disable-session-persistence-in-tomcat/)

Answer (score 1):

Open the activiti-explorer.war and change the META-INF/context.xml like so:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<Context reloadable="false">

    <!-- Disable session persistence -->
    <Manager pathname="" />

</Context>
```

To see how this affects the deployment see this documentation:
http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/manager.html#Persistence_Across_Restarts